# How can I boolean subtract a circle outline from a shape in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app

[image]

This is the result I'm getting when trying to subtract the black circle from the red triangle. What I want is for the inside of the circle to be left.

I have outlined the circle, which in reality just makes a compound shape made of two circles.

I'm using Sketch 3.7.2

Comment: I have managed to achieve my desired result, but the way I got there is insanely cumbersome. There _must_ be a better way…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in Illustrator but can be applied to Sketch.

Create a triangle and then duplicate.

Create a circle to cut out the outer edge.

Create another circle to clip the inner shape.

You should have 4 shapes now.

[image: Objects]

Select the big circle and 1 of the triangles and use Boolean Operations -> Subtract.

[image: triangle]

Select the small circle and the other triangle and use the Boolean Operations -> Intersect

Result

[image: end result]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is how I ended up solving it myself. Assuming the circle and triangle have been drawn, in Illustrator the only step that is necessary is to boolean subtract the circle from the triangle…I wonder why the same can't be done in Sketch.

Comment: @bernk What do you mean this cannot be done in Sketch? Granted I didn't test my method in Sketch but the method should still be the same. Did "Boolean Operations -> Subtract" & "Boolean Operations -> Intersect" not work?

Comment: What I mean is that while this operation is a single step in Illustrator, producing the desired result, in Sketch it requires many steps using copies of shapes and different boolean operations. If you attempt to simply subtract the circle from the triangle as shown above the result will be missing the smaller section of the triangle that should be left by the inside of the circle.

Comment: @bernk The operations should be the same amount of steps. I didn't picture that I had 2 triangles but there are 2 triangles used. In my first step I mention "Create a triangle and then **duplicate**." I will update my question so it is not misleading.

Comment: No no, your answer is fine and not misleading. We're having a communication problem here. All I'm saying is that in Illustrator it is not necessary to duplicate the triangle and perform several steps. You just have a triangle and circle and do one boolean subtract. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by selecting your circle, then go to **layer** > **convert to outlines** (cmd + shift + o);
Then you can substract the circle from the triangle :

- select the circle and the triangle
- click **substract** (top right of the screen)
- in the layers, open the combined shapes
- click on the first circle and click **union** (top right)

https://infinit.io/_/3hSQmTb

It should do the job.

Comment: I did convert to outlines, but the subtraction did not have the desired result. The inside of the circle was also missing from the triangle.

Comment: Sorry there was some missing states.